# Different behavior with browser and with curl or wget when using GeoLite2 permalink

Tags: curl, wget, geolite2

I am getting different responses when querying for the permalink provided by GeoLite2. I have created a license key and I have tested that I can download it on Incognito Mode. But when I resort to using `wget` or `curl`, I am getting an "Invalid license key" error. Anyone else experiencing the same problem? Mind sharing your work around how to solve this?

Comment: Show your curl command